# generate 3dsMax object

Tags: opengl, 3dsmax

Im coding Computer Graphich project which draws a glass in OpenGL, so I did make a glass model in 3dsMax but dont know how to generate it to file which contains co-ordinate of points of glass to use for OpenGL code. Anyone know?

Answer (score 0):

You need to write 3ds max exporter plugin using 3ds max sdk and export the model. For a beginner this is going to be extremely difficult.

Alternatively, you could export from 3dsmax into some kind of format that is easy to parse and write importer for that format in your program.

Or you could try searching for the library that can parse one of the formats 3dsmax can export.

Answer (score 0):

The following link is to a partially implemented `.3ds` loader written by: Matthew Fairfax

http://www.garagegames.com/community/resources/view/506

This was what I used while I was at university to read in objects. This loader only really includes the mesh data and possibly the material data. But if you look at the 3ds file format it should be fairly easy to get the rest of the parts reading in as well.

using google for about 20s I also found the following link which looks fairly detailed for the file format and has code at the bottom that should help you work out the loading.

http://www.martinreddy.net/gfx/3d/3DS.spec